16 bit register converting to two 8 bytes using vb.net in visual studio
converting the 16 bit data to 8 bit and then reversing it back to 16 bits
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Original 16-bit data
        Dim originalValue As UShort = &HA91

        ' Split into two 8-bit values
        Dim highByte As Byte = CByte((originalValue >> 8) And &HFF)
        Dim lowByte As Byte = CByte(originalValue And &HFF)

        ' Display the split values
        Console.WriteLine("High Byte: 0x{0:X2}", highByte)
        Console.WriteLine("Low Byte:  0x{0:X2}", lowByte)

        ' Combine the two 8-bit values back into a 16-bit value
        Dim combinedValue As UShort = CUShort((CUShort(highByte) << 8) Or CUShort(lowByte))

        ' Display the combined value
        Console.WriteLine("Combined Value: 0x{0:X3}", combinedValue)

        ' Check if the original value matches the combined value
        If originalValue = combinedValue Then
            Console.WriteLine("The values match!")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("The values do not match!")
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

i am getting 2570 instead of 2705 for hex value of &HA91

Your assuming we know a lot more than what can be gleaned from the code.  WITHOUT using code edit your question and tell us what you are doing in WORDS.

@dbasnett see at first I am just initializing &H202 then I am sending this command where I expect the output to be in Dec (1285) which is correct! But when I change the initialized val to &HA91 the output is 2507 instead of 2705 Dec why is that so? I hope its clear now

At least put the effort into formatting the code with proper line breaks so it is readable.

@nyl You need better naming for your timing objects: why does Timer500ms_Tick handle Timer590ms.Tick? There are three difficult things in programming: naming, and off-by-one errors.

@AndrewMorton kindly ignore the timer590ms, consider it as timer500mS

@nyl It looks like there are a lot of characters such as = missing from the code. Please fix them so that it looks like valid VB. You should be able to copy-and-paste from VS - you can use Alt+mouse selection to avoid excessive indentation.

@andrewMorton yes it is vb.net (the programming language) and the device ID is working just fine the only issue is with Case 2 and Case 3 , do I need to combine it back to 16 bit ? Or just use the split data ?

@AndrewMorton read now, it's fixed

@nyl There might be some data type mismatches. If you set Option Strict On for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) then Visual Studio can point out problems like that for you.

@andrewMorton so I don't have to combine the data back into 16 bit ?

It's unclear why one would need to recombine the low byte and high byte. Nonetheless, the following should resolve your issue. Change the following code
From:
' Combine the two 8-bit values back into a 16-bit value
Dim combinedValue As UShort = CUShort((highByte << 8) Or lowByte)

To:
' Combine the two 8-bit values back into a 16-bit value
Dim combinedValue As UShort = (CUShort(highByte) << 8) Or lowByte


Here's the explanation. To understand the issue, let's look at a truth table.
Truth table for conjunction (AND)



p
q
p AND q




1
1
1


1
0
0


0
1
0


0
0
0



Truth table for disjunction (OR)



p
q
p OR q




1
1
1


1
0
1


0
1
1


0
0
0



Note: I recommend using the built-in Windows calculator - using the menu to select Programmer mode. To enter a HEX value, click on HEX prior to using the keypad. Likewise, to enter a decimal value, click on DEC prior to using the keypad. As you may already know, to enter a binary value, one clicks on BIN prior to using the keypad.
Let's look at the value &HA91:

HEX: A91 (can also be written as: 0A91)
DEC: 2705
BIN: 1010 1001 0001 (can also be written as: 0000 1010 1001 0001)

The highByte (ie: most significant byte) value is: 0A (binary: 0000 1010)
The lowByte (ie: least significant byte) value is: 91 (binary: 1001 0001)
Let's look at some code:
Console.WriteLine($"shifted value: {(highByte << 8).ToString("X8")}")

Result:
shifted value: 0000000A

According to << Operator (Visual Basic):


Result: Integral numeric value. The result of shifting the bit pattern. The data type is the same as that of pattern.

Pattern: Integral numeric expression. The bit pattern to be shifted. The data type must be an integral type (SByte, Byte, Short,
UShort, Integer, UInteger, Long, or ULong).

Amount: Numeric expression. The number of bits to shift the bit pattern. The data type must be Integer or widen to Integer.


To prevent shifting by more bits than the result can hold, Visual
Basic masks the value of amount with a size mask corresponding to the
data type of pattern. The binary AND of these values is used for the shift amount. The size masks are as follows:




Data type of pattern
Size mask (decimal)
Size mask (hexadecimal)




SByte, Byte
7
&H00000007


Short, UShort
15
&H0000000F



If amount is zero, the value of result is identical to the value of pattern.
In the code in the OP, is the following:
Dim originalValue As UShort = &HA91
Dim highByte As Byte = CByte((originalValue >> 8) And &HFF)
           ...
Dim combinedValue As UShort = CUShort((highByte << 8) Or lowByte)

Let's look at the following: highByte << 8.
highByte is a Byte and a left shift by 8 is being done. According to the documentation, a check is performed.

Pattern: highByte (which is a Byte)
Amount: 8 (binary: 1000)
Size mask (decimal) for Byte (from table above): 7 (binary: 0111)




Description





8
1000


7
0111


8 AND 7
0000



As previously stated above: If amount is zero, the value of result is identical to the value of pattern (ie: highByte).
What happens if we do highByte OR lowByte?



Description






highByte
0000
1010


lowByte
1001
0001


highByte OR lowByte
1001
1011



highByte OR lowByte = 1001 1011 = Hexadecimal 9B.
What happened? One needs to have a UInt16 (or UShort) before shifting the bits left.

According to >> Operator (Visual Basic):

Note that the data types Byte, UShort, UInteger, and ULong are
unsigned, so there is no sign bit to propagate. If pattern is of any
unsigned type, the vacated positions are always set to zero.

which means:
Dim highByte As Byte = CByte((originalValue >> 8) And &HFF)

can be changed to
Dim highByte As Byte = CByte(originalValue >> 8)


Hi, thank you for your response i tried this and still i am getting 2570 instead of 2705 i have no idea why and if i enter &H202 i'd get the exact output but if &HA91 is entered i'd get 2507 instead of 2705 why is that so? @user246821

I have updated my original post with real code please go through it

@nyl:  &H202 is binary 0000 0010 0000 0010. As you can see, in binary, the value for highByte  (most significant byte) and lowByte (least significant byte) are identical. You may consider adding a URL to the documentation for your hardware device to your post. You may also check if your computer is little endian or big endian, as well as, your hardware device.

thanks for your support! my code is working now, i just had to use highbyte and low byte at some other places as well and write cushort before using lowbyte
